# How to start the autofill option from a cell in excell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a field(cell): P2 and when I type 25 I need that value to be copied to cell B53 and from this cell B53 to start autofilling and increasing the value when cell C46 is not empty anymore. Let me explain that again : So when I put a value to P2 that should be copied to B53. After that when I fill cell C46 the cell B54 would be the increased value from cell B53

Example: I put 25 in cell P2...Then cell B53 become 25...Then I put something in cell C46 so the cell B54 is autofilled with value 26.

Thanks for your help. And do not hesitate to ask any questions that you have.

Comment: New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 25 in P2 or any value you need, and in B53 write `=P2` 
In B54 write the following
`=IF(C46<>0,B53+1,"")`
or
`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C46)),B53+1,"")`
Depending on the value you write in `C46` the result in B54 will be the value in P2 + 1 if C46 is not empty and nothing if C46 is empty.

Comment: That is great mate the final formula I have used is =IF(C46; B53+1; "")